# Schedule payment of ETH from polygon network to Ethereum network

Tags: transactions, polygon, cross-chain, escrow

I want to design a contract in polygon network which receives crypto (ETH) from sender and sends it to the receiver on a timely basis may be monthly.

I am not sure if it is possible without polygon bridge. This is not a problem if transfer is done in MATIC token itself but here it is ETH.

It's something like Escrow contract with recurring ETH  payment in polygon network.

I need some expert's suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could design it in a way where the amount get unlocked and become available after X block. A Block is about 13 sec so it will give you an proximate month.

You would still need a process to activate this transaction execution and provide some gas. The contract will not be triggered because it reach a time limit.

Some easy solutions for you.

- Use a time frame to count how much is unlocked and claimable by the recipient. (User will pay the gas)
- Use a Bot. (You pay the gas)
- Use a process (transaction) that runs often and use it to trigger the transfer(at users expense in the worst way)

There are probably other solutions, For example there is a fluid token model that stream an amount over time. That token could then be turned back to ETH.

So it's really a matter of who will pay the gas for your automated task in the end.

Comment: I get it but is it really possible to transfer ETH in polygon network or not? Because it's cross-chain.Actually, a polygon bridge helps to complete the transfer. How can we do this without a polygon bridge?

Comment: You can't do this without a bridge.

Comment: That means without manual activity in polygon bridge it's not possible?